# WL.Client.connect() failed intermittently

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst

I have an android application, when I deploy it to my Samsung Galaxy Note 4, and run the apps, the first time it run, it works fine. However, if I exit out the app and activate it again, it failed to connect to the server. After several attempt to try it again, occasionally it will work again.

Here is the code that resides in wlCommonInit:

```
WL.Client.connect(
    {
        onSuccess:connectivityCheckSuccess,
        onFailure:connectivityCheckFailure,
        timeout:5000
    });
```

When it failed it will execute "connectivityCheckFailure" callback function

Here is the log showing in logcat:

```
01-12 11:49:31.099: D/NONE(17766): Request [/apps/services/api/Macros/android/init]
01-12 11:49:31.309: D/GCMClientFactory(17766): GCMClientFactory.useGooglePlayServices in GCMClientFactory.java:42 :: Google Play Services is not used because the play services library is not found. So using the default GCM helper implementation.
01-12 11:49:31.319: D/GCMIntentService(17766): GCMIntentService.doWakefulWork in GCMIntentService.java:152 :: GCMIntentService : Received a registration message from the GCM server
01-12 11:49:31.319: D/GCMIntentService(17766): GCMIntentService.onUnregistered in GCMIntentService.java:186 :: GCMIntentService: Unregistered at the GCM server
01-12 11:49:36.129: E/NONE(17766): Request timeout for [/apps/services/api/Macros/android/init]
```

Which shows the init is timing out.

Can anybody give me an idea what is wrong?

Comment: The log doesn't say much, as can be seen. Also include the server log from the time of the error and may a Wireshark log from the same time will help as well.

Comment: If you increase the timeout value, do you see the occurence coming down?

Comment: @IdanAdar: I checked server log, but it does not seem that the device is trying to make a connection to the server. The log does not get created at all. While when it is successful, I can see the log statement got created. I can try to install wireshark log

Comment: @VivinK, I have tried to increase the timeout to 10 and 15 seconds, but it has the same error

Comment: Does it also happen with other devices?